# How to get the actual result size of a SOQL

Tags: soql, soap-api

I am using SOAP API to execute a SOQL.
I need to get the size of my result

Does QueryResult.size() returns the actual size or the number of rows returned in the current execution

Consider I've a 45000 records and I want to get the count of the records.
Executing a query will result in 500 records if I didn't modify the batch size.

So my question is, does QueryResult.size() will return me 45000 or 500?
If it returns 500, is there any other way to get the count. I don't want to use select count() as the query is not constructed in my applicationm instead it is fed from some where.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the docs it's the number of records retrieved by the query, so I take that to mean 45,000 in your example:

> Your client application can use this value to determine whether the query retrieved any rows
>   (size > 0) or not (size = 0). Total number of rows retrieved in the query.

The `QueryResult` also includes a query locator which makes it easier to get the next group of records:

> ### QueryLocator
>
> In the
>   QueryResult
>   object returned by the
>   `query()`
>   call,
>   `queryLocator`
>   contains a value that you will use in the subsequent
>   `queryMore()`
>   call. Note the following guidelines:
>
> - Use a given
>     queryLocator
>     value only once. When you pass it in a
>     `queryMore()`
>     call, the
>     API
>     returns a new
>     queryLocator
>     in the
>     QueryResult
>     .
> - QueryLocator
>     objects expire automatically after 15 minutes of inactivity.